# Chef: searching node inside recipe returns error 500.

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm using Chef 11 (opensource server) and chef-client 11 also. I'm trying to search the nodes with a specific role. Using knife I am able to get the results I wish using:
`knife search node "run_list:role\[cassandra\]"`. Also I'm able to search using `search(:node, "run_list:role\\[cassandra\\]")` inside the recipe. But if I try to access the role using an attribute I cannot get it working. I have tried the most obvious way `search(:node, "run_list:role\\[#{node[:role][:cassandra]}\\]")` and also trying to compose the query outside the search line (`query = 'run_list:role\[' + node[:cassandra][:seed_role]`) but I get the same error. I'm getting error 500 during Chef-client compile phase (I think). Here it is the part of the code I'm using and the output log.

```
 # Searching for Cassandra nodes inside the same Chef environment
  cassandra_seeds = []
  cassandra_nodes_macs = []
  query = 'run_list:role\[' + node[:cassandra][:seed_role] + '\] AND chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment}'
  log query
  search(:node, query).each do |n|
#  search(:node, "run_list:role\\[cassandra\\]  AND \
#    chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment}").each do |n|
#  search(:node, "roles:*#{node[:cassandra][:seed_role]}  AND \
#    chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment}").each do |n|
    cassandra_seeds << n[:fqdn] unless n[:fqdn] == node[:fqdn]
  end
```

---

```
$ kitchen converge ub
-----> Starting Kitchen (v1.2.1)
-----> Converging <default-ubuntu-1404>...
       Preparing files for transfer
       Resolving cookbook dependencies with Berkshelf 3.2.1...
       Removing non-cookbook files before transfer
       Preparing data bags
       Preparing nodes
       Preparing encrypted data bag secret
       bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
       bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
       Transfering files to <default-ubuntu-1404>
       bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
       [2015-01-19T15:33:52+00:00] INFO: Starting chef-zero on port 8889 with repository at repository at /tmp/kitchen
         One version per cookbook

       [2015-01-19T15:33:52+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
       Starting Chef Client, version 11.10.4
       [2015-01-19T15:33:52+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.10.4 ***
       [2015-01-19T15:33:52+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 2711
       [2015-01-19T15:33:52+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[apt]", "recipe[cassandra::default]"] from JSON
       [2015-01-19T15:33:52+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[apt], recipe[cassandra::default]]
       [2015-01-19T15:33:52+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [apt, cassandra::default]
       [2015-01-19T15:33:52+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for default-ubuntu-1404
       [2015-01-19T15:33:52+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
       [2015-01-19T15:33:52+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
       [2015-01-19T15:33:52+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found: Object not found: /reports/nodes/default-ubuntu-1404/runs
       resolving cookbooks for run list: ["apt", "cassandra::default"]
       [2015-01-19T15:33:53+00:00] INFO: Loading cookbooks [apt, ark, cassandra, java, line, sysctl, ulimit, user, yum]
       Synchronizing Cookbooks:
         - apt
       [2015-01-19T15:33:53+00:00] INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/configure.rb in the cache.
         - cassandra
         - user
         - java
         - ulimit
         - yum
         - ark
         - sysctl
         - line
       Compiling Cookbooks...
       [2015-01-19T15:33:54+00:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for execute[apt-get-update-periodic] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
       [2015-01-19T15:33:54+00:00] WARN: Previous execute[apt-get-update-periodic]: /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/apt/recipes/default.rb:80:in `from_file'
       (...)
       [2015-01-19T15:33:54+00:00] ERROR: #<RuntimeError: Error on token 'node.chef_environment' at 72 of 'run_list:role\[cassandra\] AND chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment}': Expected TO in range query>
       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-zero-1.7.3/lib/chef_zero/solr/solr_parser.rb:117:in `parse_error'
       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-zero-1.7.3/lib/chef_zero/solr/solr_parser.rb:147:in `read_single_expression'
       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-zero-1.7.3/lib/chef_zero/solr/solr_parser.rb:100:in `read_expression'
       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-zero-1.7.3/lib/chef_zero/solr/solr_parser.rb:17:in `parse'
       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-zero-1.7.3/lib/chef_zero/endpoints/search_endpoint.rb:95:in `search'
       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-zero-1.7.3/lib/chef_zero/endpoints/search_endpoint.rb:13:in `get'
       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-zero-1.7.3/lib/chef_zero/rest_base.rb:29:in `call'
       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-zero-1.7.3/lib/chef_zero/rest_router.rb:23:in `call'
       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-zero-1.7.3/lib/chef_zero/server.rb:335:in `block in make_app'
       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/puma-1.6.3/lib/puma/server.rb:412:in `call'
       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/puma-1.6.3/lib/puma/server.rb:412:in `handle_request'
       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/puma-1.6.3/lib/puma/server.rb:306:in `process_client'
       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/puma-1.6.3/lib/puma/server.rb:215:in `block in run'

       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/puma-1.6.3/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:94:in `call'
       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/puma-1.6.3/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:94:in `block in spawn_thread'
       [2015-01-19T15:33:54+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 500 Internal Server Error: error

       ================================================================================
       Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/default.rb
       ================================================================================


       Net::HTTPFatalError
       -------------------
       500 "Internal Server Error"


       Cookbook Trace:
       ---------------
         /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/configure.rb:41:in `from_file'
         /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/default.rb:35:in `from_file'


       Relevant File Content:
       ----------------------
       /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/cassandra/recipes/configure.rb:

        34:  else
        35:    old_token = node[:cassandra][:token]
        36:    # Searching for Cassandra nodes inside the same Chef environment

        37:    cassandra_seeds = []
        38:    cassandra_nodes_macs = []
        39:    query = 'run_list:role\[' + node[:cassandra][:seed_role] + '\] AND chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment}'
        40:    log query
        41>>   search(:node, query).each do |n|
        42:  #  search(:node, "run_list:role\\[cassandra\\]  AND \
        43:  #    chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment}").each do |n|
        44:  #  search(:node, "roles:*#{node[:cassandra][:seed_role]}  AND \
        45:  #    chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment}").each do |n|
        46:      cassandra_seeds << n[:fqdn] unless n[:fqdn] == node[:fqdn]
        47:    end
        48:  
        49:    cassandra_nodes_macs << node[:macaddress] unless cassandra_nodes_macs.include?(node[:macaddress])
        50:  




       Running handlers:
       [2015-01-19T15:33:54+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
       Running handlers complete

       [2015-01-19T15:33:54+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
       [2015-01-19T15:33:54+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/kitchen/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
       Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 1.955433697 seconds
       [2015-01-19T15:33:54+00:00] ERROR: 500 "Internal Server Error"
       [2015-01-19T15:33:54+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
>>>>>> Converge failed on instance <default-ubuntu-1404>.
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/default-ubuntu-1404.log for more details
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: SSH exited (1) for command: [sudo -E chef-client -z --config /tmp/kitchen/client.rb --log_level info --json-attributes /tmp/kitchen/dna.json]
>>>>>> ----------------------
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After comment I played with chef-shell (to try search in the same context as a recipe)

Valid syntax I found to work (no quote around role name):

- `search(:node, 'run_list:role\[mysql-server-wso2\] AND chef_environment:I1')`
- `search(:node, "run_list:role\\[mysql-server-wso2\\] AND chef_environment:I1")`

The double quote way sounds easiest for variable interpolation.
Exemple with your case:

```
query = "run_list:role\\[#{node[:cassandra][:seed_role]}\\] AND chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment}"
```

You may ensure it is properly interpolated by adding a log line just after like this:

```
Chef::Log.info "Query is: #{query}"
```

---

Old Answer:
I don't know why you set this in single quotes, but its likely your problem:

```
 query = 'run_list:role\[' + node[:cassandra][:seed_role] + '\] AND chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment}'
```

Being in single quote, #{node.chef_environment} is not substitued and is sent to chef server as is, which the server can't resolv properly and fail with a 500 error.

Written like this the query should be ok:

```
query = "run_list:role['#{node[:cassandra][:seed_role]}'] AND chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment}"
```

Comment: I tried it but not working. I'm getting the same error. I used simple quotes to compose the query string using literal plus the attribute field, but I get the same issue. I think the query is composed correctly, but there is some issue in Chef compile time that breaks it. Thanks.

Comment: When I search using the role directly (not as a attribute/ruby variable) it works. The problem arises when the role pattern is an attribute (or ruby variable...) i.e.: I have to write `#{variable}` in the query. Thanks.

Comment: @jcortejoso For the run you pasted on the question the error is clear: ` [2015-01-19T15:33:54+00:00] ERROR: #<RuntimeError: Error on token 'node.chef_environment' at 72 of 'run_list:role\[cassandra\] AND chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment}': Expected TO in range query>` was my first answer, no interpolation of variable within single quotes. I updated my answer with variables

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. I thought I was tried your solution but probably I missed something.

Comment: @jcortejoso according to what is commented in your code, the backslash to continue line was probably your problem, ruby does not understand this as an instruction may be spanned on multi line until it's closing char (quote, braces, etc.)

Comment: Good to now. Thanks for your help.